# Django URL Parameters get deleted

Tags: python, django, url, query-string

Hey guys I'm having a problem passing URL parameters in my Django code. 
Let say i have a url like below:

```
/search/?q=django
```

and in one of my form I have a href to add another parameter like

```
<a href="?price=all"> ... </a>
```

But when I actually click the href link I end up with:

```
search/?price=all
```

and the django spits out a

> ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value

any idea of why this is happening??

Comment: Well this is really not the way how to add a `GET` parameter.

Comment: I'm following this article  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html and it use to work before. IDK where the hell i changed something

Comment: Well the article actually is entirely intended to *move away* from that approach...

Comment: yea I know. Ask the question that way to see if it was easier to get an answer. I code that template tag too and it worked before but now It just replace the existing query url parameter

Comment: I don't understand why this surprises you. You have a URL which contains one parameter, you click on a URL which doesn't contain that parameter, why would you think your original parameter would be there?

Comment: I have done it like this before and it used to add the parameter on top of any existing one